# How to test if a PreparedStatement is going to run out of memory

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

so I have some java code using JDBC to insert data into a PostgreSQL database using a prepared statement which looks a little like this:

```
PreparedStatement statement = // prep statement

for (int value: values) {

    statement.setInt(1, value);
    statement.addBatch();
}

statement.executeBatch();
```

The problem is, I'm occasionally hitting the exception `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.  I've taken a look around, but I can't find anything on it; how do I test if the statement is about to run out of memory so that I can execute a batch.  Something like this:

```
PreparedStatement statement = // prep statement

for (int value: values) {

    statement.setInt(1, value);
    statement.addBatch();

    if (statement.currentSize() + sizeof(int) > statement.mazSize()) {

        statement.executeBatch();
    }
}

statement.executeBatch();
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you closing all the resources you create - prepared statement, resultset, etc?

Comment: When I batch statements I have a look at the memory consumption and flush them after `% x == 0`. You could monitor the free heap space but I was just to lazy for that.

Comment: Use a smaller batch size say 500 and execute iteratively.

Comment: I assume you close `statement` afterwards? That can be a leak. Did `setAutocommit(false), ... commit()` or on exception `rollback()`? Hardly can imagine that that OutOfMemoryError. Beside the exception you saw the stacktrace I assume.

Comment: Hi all, sorry I missed that off; yes I do close the resources.  this isn't actually what the code looks like, it's just a simplification.  My question was more, in the past I've just used constants to determine the batch size, but I don't know the specifics of the target machine my code is deployed on, so I'd like to be able to cope with differing amount of available memory.

Comment: What is the size of your `values` array when this error occurs ? I am seeing this happening in my app too though one strange pattern that I found is that this error doesn't cause any data commit issues. Data gets saved to DB as error happens at JVM level few moments later.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reliable way to find out in advance whether an instantiation will fail.

However, more to the point: you are probably misusing the JDBC batching facility, which is there to solve the issue of network roundtrip overhead when  inserting many rows. Batch sizes of anything above 100 show diminishing returns and may actually result in slowdowns.

So, change your batching policy to use fixed batch size of a smallish, double-digit integer.

Comment: Writing 10m entries in a full isolated transaction, I found out, that based on the used db config, less than 1k entries before flush slowed done the whole process.

Comment: @hannes How far away, network-wise, was the DB? In any reasonable production system it's very close. The longer the roundtrip, the larger the batch size needed.

Comment: It was just a hop away but on heavy use. It was my first mariadb, so I invested the time to just fine tune it in the end. But your statement holds with db2, oracle and sqlserver.

Comment: Is this the only option?  I'm happy to limit the batch size to something smaller, but I don't chose the target machine, so I have no idea if the arbitrary number I assign will cause an out of memory exception.  Is there any way I can calculate what I've got to work with?  I don't know if this makes a different, but it's single threaded at the point of this call.

Comment: To get an OOME you really need an insanely large batch size. Just give it a reasonably small size.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue with a code similar to yours because it was assumed that input array / list ( `values`) size would at max be in triple digits - that was an assumption at code level that developer who coded it had.

And one fine day, array / list came to be close to 14k and this code caused OOM though one thing that I noticed that data successfully got committed to DB ( Its Db2 + Oracle Weblogic Set up ) & few seconds later after few OOMs , system went down.

To fix the issue, I simply put `statement.executeBatch();` at a pre decided fixed size like below assuming fixed batch size to be 100,

```
int counter = 0;
for (int value: values) {
    statement.setInt(1, value);
    statement.addBatch();
    ++counter;
    if(counter >= 100 ){
     statement.executeBatch();
     counter =0;
   }
}
statement.executeBatch();
```

I am not sure if this has anything to do with drivers too but I would assume this fixed number of batches is going to vary from set up to set up infra wise ( I have a multi node powerful DB2 cluster & Web App is also located in same data center )  and I have tested multiple sizes and 1000 goes fairly fast with out any issues but I reduced the size because this code gets kicked from an online UI app so there could be multiple triggers for same code.

I guess it would depend on both - number of Statement objects that one can keep in memory & how long DB takes to process one submitted batch because code will be waiting that long.